# Ecto Multi.run returns clause matching anonymous fn/2 error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the following Ecto.Multi but it throws an error. I'm running on `Phoenix 1.6.15` with `Ecto 3.9.2`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

**Code:**

```elixir
    result =
        Multi.new()
        |> Multi.run(:line_items, fn _, {:ok, line_items} ->
          Orders.update_line_items_state(order)
          {:ok, line_items}
        end)
        |> Multi.run(:approve_order, fn params, {:ok, _changes} ->
          Repo.update(
            Order.changeset(order, %{
              state: "confirmed",
              total: Orders.calculate_order_total(params.line_items)
            })
          )
        end)
        |> Multi.run(:payment, fn _, {:ok, _changes} ->
          create_payment(%{
            payment_method: "credit",
            order_id: order.id,
            amount: amount,
            payment_state: "approved"
          })
        end)
        |> Repo.transaction()
```

**Error:**

```elixir
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/payment/charge
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/2 in Pxrf.Payments.execute_payment/4
        (pxrf 0.1.0) anonymous fn(Pxrf.Repo, %{}) in Pxrf.Payments.execute_payment/4
        (ecto 3.9.4) lib/ecto/multi.ex:832: Ecto.Multi.apply_operation/5
        (elixir 1.14.2) lib/enum.ex:2468: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (ecto 3.9.4) lib/ecto/multi.ex:806: anonymous fn/5 in Ecto.Multi.apply_operations/5
        (ecto_sql 3.9.2) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:1203: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.checkout_or_transaction/4
        (db_connection 2.4.3) lib/db_connection.ex:1611: DBConnection.run_transaction/4
        (ecto 3.9.4) lib/ecto/repo/transaction.ex:18: Ecto.Repo.Transaction.transaction/4
        (pxrf 0.1.0) lib/pxrf/payments/payments.ex:249: Pxrf.Payments.execute_payment/4
        (pxrf 0.1.0) lib/pxrf_web/controllers/payment_controller.ex:427: PxrfWeb.PaymentController.charge/2
        (pxrf 0.1.0) lib/pxrf_web/controllers/payment_controller.ex:1: PxrfWeb.PaymentController.action/2
        (pxrf 0.1.0) lib/pxrf_web/controllers/payment_controller.ex:1: PxrfWeb.PaymentController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (phoenix 1.6.16) lib/phoenix/router.ex:354: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
        (pxrf 0.1.0) lib/pxrf_web/endpoint.ex:1: PxrfWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (pxrf 0.1.0) lib/plug/debugger.ex:136: PxrfWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (pxrf 0.1.0) lib/pxrf_web/endpoint.ex:1: PxrfWeb.Endpoint.call/2
        (phoenix 1.6.16) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:54: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/4
        (cowboy 2.9.0) /User/project/pxrf/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl:37: :cowboy_handler.execute/2
        (cowboy 2.9.0) /User/project/pxrf/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:306: :cowboy_stream_h.execute/3
        (cowboy 2.9.0) /User/project/pxrf/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:295: :cowboy_stream_h.request_process/3
        (stdlib 4.1.1) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Need some help to fix this issue..

**Code Edit:**

```elixir
    result =
        Multi.new()
        |> Multi.run(:line_items, fn _repo, {:ok, _line_items} ->
          line_item = Orders.update_line_items_state(order)
          {:ok, line_item}
        end)
        |> Multi.run(:approve_orderm, fn _repo, {:ok, line_item} ->
          Repo.update(
            Order.changeset(order, %{
              state: "confirmed",
              total: Orders.calculate_order_total(line_item)
            })
          )
        end)
        |> Multi.run(:payment, fn _repo, {:ok, _changes} ->
          create_payment(%{
            payment_method: "credit",
            order_id: order.id,
            amount: amount,
            payment_state: "approved"
          })
        |> Repo.transaction()
```

Here is the full error details and the modified code. Upon updating to the new code and it still throws an error. Not sure it has to do with the controller or the Multi.run() part?

The changes in the above code.

1. Multi.run() added the repo for each run.

Comment: Logic here is First run calculates the line_items and second run should use that updated line_item and update the Order which followed by create_payment function which insert and Repo transaction. Operation: Calculate > Update > Insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even despite you have cut the most significant part of the error message off, I’d wild guess that [changes accepted as the second argument](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#run/3) by a runner cannot be a tuple.

The first argument is always a repo, not some “params” or whatever.

That said, instead of

```elixir
|> Multi.run(:line_items, fn _, {:ok, line_items} ->
```

you would want somewhat like

```elixir
|> Multi.run(:line_items, fn _repo, %{line_items: line_items} ->
```

Also it **must** return either `{:ok, value}` or `{:error, value}`, as it is clearly stated in the documentation I linked above.

Comment: I've modified the code and edited the post with full error. But still it throws error. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: The second argument in a call to anonymous function inside `Multi.run/3` would be **changes**, as it is stated by both documentation and my answer above. Changes would be a map that would not match `{:ok, whatever}` tuple. If you want to discard the changes from the previous step (despite I am questioning why would you need `multi` there then,) just do `fn _, _ ->`.

Comment: That worked. Great. Thanks for promptly answers. Cheers.